# How can I set node js version in Vue app for vercel deployment?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have an Vue.js app that I deploy on Vercel. Deploying was going well until recently when I got this build error on Vercel:

> Error: Node.js Version "14.x" is discontinued and must be upgraded. Please set Node.js Version to 18.x in your Project Settings to use Node.js 18.

The problem is that I do not know where in Vue app should node version be set?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Go to project settings > General > Node JS Version and change it to 16.x or 18.x

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is the Vercel issue. You go on `settings` page and select the newer version of node.js

[image]